# D3.js collapsible tree force all expanded layout to stay

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, geometry

I am trying to modify the collapsible tree found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

By removing the following line, we get the tree with all of the nodes expanded:

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

When I collapse or expand a branch, the spacing of the parent of this branch and their siblings always get a different distance from eachother. What I would like to do is to keep the distance of every branch regardless of them being expanded or not (the parent and sibling would always keep the same distance.

Here's a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fg83oo8p/) of the expanded tree.